# I have these errors : PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to realize this problem:
Create stored procedure which will print the most purchased product (as raw material for pizzeria). From which it will print the name of that product, the purchase price, the sale price, the quantity of the product purchased in total and the total value of all purchases made of that product.

I do not know how to correct the error.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY ON
SET ECHO ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE imprimir_producto_mas_comprado IS
  v_proid         producto.proid%TYPE;
  v_nombre        producto.pronombre%TYPE;
  v_valor_compra  producto.provalorcompra%TYPE;
  v_valor_venta   producto.provalorventa%TYPE;
  v_cantidad_total compra.comcantidad%TYPE;
  v_valor_total   compra.comcantidad%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT p.pronombre, p.provalorcompra, p.provalorventa, SUM(c.comcantidad) AS cantidad_total, 
         SUM(c.comcantidad * p.provalorcompra) AS valor_total
  INTO v_nombre, v_valor_compra, v_valor_venta, v_cantidad_total, v_valor_total
  FROM producto p
  JOIN compra c ON p.proid = c.proid
  GROUP BY p.pronombre, p.provalorcompra, p.provalorventa
  ORDER BY cantidad_total
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROW ONLY
  INTO v_proid, v_nombre, v_valor_compra, v_valor_venta, v_cantidad_total, v_valor_total;
 

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Producto más comprado: ' || v_nombre);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Precio de compra: ' || v_valor_compra);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Precio de venta: ' || v_valor_venta);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cantidad total comprada: ' || v_cantidad_total);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Valor total de todas las compras: ' || v_valor_total);
END;

EXECUTE imprimir_producto_mas_comprado;
```

Comment: Obvious mistakes: only one INTO clause per SELECT statement (you have two). Fetching more than a single row into scalar variables will result in TOO_MANY_ROWS; either use a collection, or a loop.

Comment: The immediate error is that you need a `/` on a line on its own between `END;` and `EXECUTE` (and assuming you're running this as a script in SQL Developer, or in SQL\*Plus). Then you'll be able to see all the other errors *8-)

Comment: My advice when unsure of the syntax is to start with something as simple as possible (one table, one variable, dummy data) and make sure that works and you are comfortable with it before gradually adding in the full details. Otherwise you can find yourself with a page of code showing multiple errors and no clear idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors include:

- No `/` statement terminator on a new-line after the `END;` of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` block.
- Having a second `INTO` in the `SELECT` statement after `FETCH FIRST ...`
- Not having the same number of values in the `SELECT` clause as the variables in the (second, erroneous) `INTO` clause.
- Using `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...` when the query will return more than one row (you either want `SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ... FROM ...` with collection variables or to use a cursor).

If you want to rewrite it using a cursor then your procedure would be:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE imprimir_producto_mas_comprado IS
BEGIN
  FOR rw IN (
    SELECT p.pronombre,
           p.provalorcompra,
           p.provalorventa,
           SUM(c.comcantidad) AS cantidad_total, 
           SUM(c.comcantidad * p.provalorcompra) AS valor_total
    FROM   producto p
           JOIN compra c ON p.proid = c.proid
    GROUP BY p.pronombre, p.provalorcompra, p.provalorventa
    ORDER BY cantidad_total
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROW ONLY
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Producto más comprado: ' || rw.pronombre);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Precio de compra: ' || rw.provalorcompra);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Precio de venta: ' || rw.provalorventa);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cantidad total comprada: ' || rw.cantidad_total);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Valor total de todas las compras: ' || rw.valor_total);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V2IujGV0)